# If $q-1$ is a prime, prove that every nonzero element of $GF(q)$ not equal to the unit element 1 is primitive.

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

**If $q-1$ is a prime, prove that every nonzero element of $GF(q)$ not equal to the unit element 1 is primitive.**

What I understand is that if $q-1$ is prime then, $q$ is not prime unless these are the first 2 primes, i.e. 2 and 3.  As there are no 2 consecutive prime numbers except 2 and 3.
Can you please explain this?

Answer (score 3):

$GF(q)$ makes sense for $q>1$ being a power of a prime. Therefore, the scope of the discussion is not only $q=3$, but also all $q$ such that $q-1$ is a [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime). It should be noted that the result itself is extremely basic, and that it doesn't require addressing the complications of working with Mersenne primes.